# Ubuntu 20.04: Epson Stylus SX325W (and possibly more) are recognized, but print is wrong

Tags: printing, epson

When adding an Epson Stylus SX235W (and possibly others) there is no error, but prints are heavily misaligned: colors are vertically off of centimetres. Driver is epson-201108w and model is recognized as "Epson Stylus Scan 2500 foomatic/stcolor"

Answer (score 0):

Before installing the printer, install the package printer-driver-gutenprint. Then, install the printer, it will be recognized as "Epson Stylus SX215+Gutenprint v5.3.3" and will work correctly.

Comment: As an additional note: in my previous Ubuntu 20.04 installation the printer installed but had an error on printing and I installed the package looking at CUPS logs. In a fresh installation, no error is shown, the prints work but with totally misaligned colors. I think this is a regression, I'm going to open a bug report.